# How can I can wait for a fetch result?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I'me giving my first steps with fetching APIs and I'm definitely missing something.

I want to have a single function that accepts a query as a parameter and fetches data from the API:

```
const fetchImgs = (query) => {
  fetch(`http://www.splashbase.co/api/v1/images/search?query=${query}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data.images)
    .catch((err) => {
      displayAlert(err)
    })
}
```

And then I want to do something with the data received. For instance on window load I want to populate a carousel with forest images or when I click a button I want to populate an album with beach images. Something like this:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const forestsArray = fetchImgs("forest")
  populateCarousel(forestsArray)
}

mainImgBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const beachesArray = fetchImgs("beaches")
  populateAlbum(beachesArray)
})
```

I know I could fetch my images everytime I need them and inside the 2nd `then` I could call functions to populate stuff but I'm curious if there is any way (and if it actually makes sense) to make my `fetchImgs()` function reusable. Because the problem is that when I'm invoking my `populate` functions I still don't have access to the data from `fetchImgs()` and I cannot do `fetchImgs().then(something)` because `fetchImgs()` doesn't return a promise.

I am also aware that I could wrap my `populate` functions on a `setTimeout` but that's kinda dirty I think. Is there any better way?

Comment: `const fetchImgs = (query) => { return fetch(); } fetchImgs("forest").then(populateCarousel);`

Comment: "*…because `fetchImgs()` doesn't return a promise.*" - that is exactly the problem you need to fix

Comment: so by returning the whole fetch statement I'm returning a promise?